# Editing spelling/grammar vs. personality

Tags: discussion, review, edits

Just looking for a little guidance here... is there a 'language standard' for edits? While reviewing edits, I see some that say 'correcting grammar', but sometimes that's really just removing poster personality... i.e. replacing 'wanna' with 'want to', 'I'm' with 'I am', things like that.

I suppose that probably some standards are in order - i.e. modifying all-lower-case posts to have 'normal' punctuation probably a good thing. But I like seeing the personality quirks of different posters too, and don't want to lose that completely. What's the right line here? Maybe it's already in the guidelines and I just missed it.

Comment: We need to be clear on the fact that `s/I'm/I am/` is a stylistic change, but `s/wanna/want to/` is in fact a grammatical _correction_. "wanna" isn't proper written English.

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is very much an international web site. Non-standard English does a disservice to our readers for whom English is not their native language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such official language standard, no. A correct use of the English language (or its American variant) would be about as official as it gets.

Changing "I'm" to "I am" would be something I would reject when it comes up in a review. Assuming of course that such edits are the only ones. If it's part of an overall set of valid edits, I'd let it go.

As for more informal language such as "wanna", well, it make me wanna hurt innocent creatures. And you would not want me to hurt innocent creatures, would you? But cruelty aside, I'd consider an edit to "want to" a correction and not merely a personal choice. In fact, if an edit would be very minor, and skip over several wanna-s, I might even reject it.

Personality is often used/abused to justify poor quality posts. I can't find it at the moment, but I have been in several discussions here where the OP insisted that their lower-case "i" was part of their personality and shouldn't be touched. And that's something I just don't agree with. Nor does text speak make your post any more personal. Personality will shine through in your phrasing of a post, the humour you inject, or how poetic or straight to the point you are. And that I tend to leave intact, as long as it doesn't distract from the question asked or point made.

Other than that, standard English/American please.

Comment: So as a generally guideline: Incorrect grammar (quirks like 'wanna') - always fix. Stylistic changes (both are correct, but different) - ambivalent, prefer not to change but not strongly. sounds good.

Comment: If the changes are purely stylistic (and the original is not wrong), I'd reject. If those stylistic changes are part of a larger set of actual corrections, those corrections would make me approve.

Comment: I'm on board with this answer, but just as a side observation from the linguistics peanut gallery, it'll be interesting to see whether something we can call "English, the Indian variant" will make its way into the acceptable list in the next five to ten years.

Comment: Disregarding that @JoshCaswell, I fear that even on the points made above, I am (or we are) fighting a losing battle.